# Magento2 theme changed after language change

Tags: magento2

I created a new theme and I added Multilingual support.
When I change the language, the theme also changes.
So, please help me how to remain my selected theme after the language changed.

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

`Admin > Content > Theme > Configuration`

Make sure that the language (Store View) are using the same Theme under the `Theme Name` column. If it is not the same, click edit and update the theme to your preferred theme and hit save. ***After that, you need to make sure that you flush the cache. You can follow this guide [here](https://magemojo.com/kb/knowledge-base/clear-magento-2-cache/) if you don't know how to do it***.

See similar image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ner!!, working now after theme settings as per your suggestion

Comment: @pukhrajsuthar please accept this answer. :)